# RewriteRule definition not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I have the following RewriteRule without any other RewriteRule definitions

```
RewriteRule ^de/(var)/(.+) /$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Then everything works fine

But when I have the following RewriteRule as well in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Then the first RewriteRule does not work.

Comment: What is your intent for each of the rules?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is how your should keep both rules:

```
RewriteRule ^de/(var)/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de/var/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution below should fix your immediate problem.

A better solution could be provided if you supply details about the intent of your rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^de/(var)/(.+) /$1/$2 [NC,L]

#prevent internal redirects
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```